# PHP ftp_get download zero bytes files

Tags: php, ftp

in a PHP project, I need to download CSV files from a FTP server. I'm using PHP ftp_XXX function to do this.

I'm working on two separate computers, one can download FTP files with no problem; the other one initiate the FTP connection, open and create a file on my disk but after a few seconds (sounds like a timeout), the script end with this error:

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection for...
```

I've already tried to use passive mode, the connection is closed at the end of my script and the strange thing is that this is working on another computer, and on my server.

So here are my questions:
1) do you have any idea why this is happening?
2) are there configuration in php.ini or apache to enable properly PHP FTP?

Thanks you.

Cyril

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? If so how did you solved this?

Comment: Nope, the only solution I have is to work with the working computer :/ I think there is something in the Apache / PHP configuration blocking FTP connection but can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you exceeded maximum execution time.
Try to increase it:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php